# stopping an skaction upon collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody, skaction

For my project I need to be able to shoot an object and have it stop exactly where it first struck the wall.  I'm using an skaction to move it in the direction I clicked on and didbegincontact to find when it collides with the wall, but it often starts to go through the wall before it registers the collision.

Here's how I shoot:

```
var offset: CGPoint = rwSub(location, b: player.position);
                var direction = rwNormalize(offset);
                var shootAmount = rwMult(direction, b: 1000);
                var realDest = rwAdd(shootAmount, b: player.position);
                var velocity = 480.0/1.0;
                var realMoveDuration = Double(self.frame.size.width) / velocity;
                var actionMove:SKAction =  SKAction.moveTo(realDest, duration: realMoveDuration)
                println("\(realDest)")
                firstFormed = true
                portal1.runAction(actionMove)
```

Here's the physics body of the projectile:

```
 body.affectedByGravity = false
            body.categoryBitMask = firstPort
            body.collisionBitMask = wallCategory
            body.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
            body.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
            body.allowsRotation = false
            body.restitution = 1
            self.physicsBody = body
```

I need to get the point where the projectile first strikes an object and determine if its the bottom left, bottom right, center left, center right, top left, or top right of the object.  Right now it sometimes strikes the bottom of the object, but doesn't recognize the collision until its part of the way through the object, resulting in it being added to the top.

Comment: this is because move actions don't respect physics, if you want correct physics behavior you have to move the node via physics, ie applyForce/applyImpulse

Comment: any advice on how to get the angle right with applyforce/applyimpulse?